# Collada and Jogl

Tags: java, jogl, collada

I am creating WWJ (World Wind Java SDK) based application. I want to import Collada objects and was looking for library that would parse and render Collada objets. I found Xith3d, java
game 3d engine, which is able to render collada objects, but as i was looking in the code it is almost impossible to use it in existing application.

Can anyone point me where to look. Is there any library/engine which can be used just 
to load Collada model and use it in existing Jogl applicaiton.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ardor3D supports Collada but you will have to tinker it a little bit if you don't want to use the whole engine.

Answer (score 1):

SceneJS has a translator Collada -> JSON

JSON is pretty easy to work with.